# Fermat's Little Theorem question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For the statements, $$x\equiv 4\pmod 5\,\, \text{ and} \,\, x\equiv 14 \pmod {15}$$ What are the $3^{rd}$ smallest positive integers for both statements?

Comment: The 3rd smallest positive integer is 3.

Comment: The stated problem has nothing to do with Fermat's little theorem. Perhaps there is more to the problem?

Comment: Do you require $x$ to be a solution to _both_ congruences?

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv4\pmod 5\iff x=5k+4$ where $k$ is integer

So if $5k+4>0,k\ge 0$

So, the third smallest positive integer will be due to $k=2  $   i.e.,  $x=2\cdot5+4=14$

The second case can handled similarly.